# CSS Difference between Max-Height vs Height in computed properties

Tags: css

I have been burning some brains for the past 2 hours trying to figure this out.

I have a fixed element element which the height is set by max-height:60%. It's child has height set by height:100%, but it does not read correctly the parent's height unless it's specified by height and not max-height.

I need the outer element set by max-height, and the inner element to limit its size accordingly, but I can't find a solution. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raphadko/pe7gdms3/1/

```
<div style="position:fixed; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); top:50%; left:50%; max-height:60%; overflow:hidden; padding:50px; background:blue">
     <div style="background:red; overflow:hidden; height:100%;"> 
          Content
     </div>
</div>
```

I hope the question is not too confusing, the fiddle shows the example better.

Comment: max-height, unfortunately, has no effect on the computed value of height.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot "Set" the height of an element using max-height.  The max-height property can only be used to restrict the maximum height of the element.  So if you desire a specific height you have to set it using  height property.

If for any reason you want to avoid height property you can work around it by using max-height and min-height to the same value though.

Fiddle for the second part 
http://jsfiddle.net/pe7gdms3/3/

```
<div style="position:fixed; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); top:50%; left:50%; max-height:60%;min-height:60%; overflow:hidden; padding:50px; background:blue">
    <div style="background:red; overflow:hidden; height:100%;"> 
    <h2>If the parent div has height set instead of max-height, the sizing would be fine.</h2>
    <ul style="height:auto; overflow:hidden;">
        <li>LOL</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```